# Images are not loading with picasso when used with okhttp

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I am using the below code to load imges into the imageview in android

```
Picasso.with(context).load(finalImg)
                .transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4))
                .resize(100, 100).centerCrop()
                .into(viewHolder.profileImage);
```

### Observation:

- This code works perfectly fine when i use just Picasso with http
  library
- But i have not replaced network library with `okhttp-2.3.0.jar`
- Also i have used `okio-1.3.0.jar`, `okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar`

### What is happening:

- My images are not loading

### Error-log:

```
Could not find method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util.emptySink, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine
```

### How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

### I found the solution to my question:

1. I replaced above specifications .... with but replaced
   `okhttp-urlconnection-2.0.0.jar` with
   `okhttp-urlconnection-2.2.0.jar`
2. Now i am able to load images properly

### So right combo for me was

- okhttp-2.3.0.jar
- okhttp-urlconnection-2.2.0.jar
- okio-1.3.0.jar
- picasso-2.4.0.jar